# POST request with multipart data in spring webflux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-restcontroller, spring5

***i am working with spring webflux  when i added security to my app,the multipart or payload data on POST request coudnt be found in the controller, you can find below my security configuration class and my custom webfilter class***

```
 import java.util.Collections;
    
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
        import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableReactiveMethodSecurity;
        import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
        import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.SecurityWebFiltersOrder;
        import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
        import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;
        import org.springframework.security.web.server.csrf.CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository;
        import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
        import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsConfigurationSource;
        import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
        
        @EnableWebFluxSecurity 
        @EnableReactiveMethodSecurity 
        public class SecurityConfiguration {
        
            @Bean
            public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
                // @formatter:off
                return http
                        .csrf()
                            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()) 
                            .and().addFilterBefore( new CustomWebFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.ANONYMOUS_AUTHENTICATION)
                        .authorizeExchange()
                            .pathMatchers("/ws/**").permitAll() 
                            .anyExchange().authenticated()
                            .and()
                        .oauth2Login()
                            .and()
                        .oauth2ResourceServer()
                            .jwt().and().and().build();
                // @formatter:on
            }
        
            @Bean 
            CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
                CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
                configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
                configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:4200"));
                configuration.addAllowedMethod(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
                configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
                source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
                return source;
            }
        }
```

this is my custom webfilter class
i made a cutom filter for multipart filter to integrate it in spring security chain but the problem is that the filter is servlet based

```
  import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
    import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter;
    import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
    import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
    import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;
    
    import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
    import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
    
    @Component
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @Slf4j
    public class CustomWebFilter implements WebFilter {
    
      @Override
      public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        log.info("My Custom Web Filter.");
        new MultipartFilter();//java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
        return chain.filter(exchange);
      }
    }
```

this is the original error that is raised when i call the controller to save a file

{
"timestamp": "2021-04-01T17:17:26.373+00:00",
"path": "/users/addPhoto/60648bfa9b3b60106bdabc93",
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"message": "Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present",
"requestId": "a763eee0-16",
"trace": "org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebInputException: 400 BAD_REQUEST "Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present" at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:114) Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: Error has been observed at the following site(s): |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain] |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain] |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain] |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain] |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain] |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.ui.LogoutPageGeneratingWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain] |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.ui.LoginPageGeneratingWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain] |_ checkpoint ⇢ tn.talan.cra.security.CustomWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain] |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$OAuth2ResourceServerSpec$BearerTokenAuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain] |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.authentication.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain] |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain] |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain] |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.csrf.CsrfWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain] |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain] |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain] |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain] |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain] |_ checkpoint ⇢ tn.talan.cra.security.CustomWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain] |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/users/addPhoto/60648bfa9b3b60106bdabc93" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler] Stack trace: at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:114) at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueArgumentResolver.lambda$getDefaultValue$1(AbstractNamedValueArgumentResolver.java:215) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSupplier.subscribe(MonoSupplier.java:56) at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4046) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:81) at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:136) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:144) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMap.java:53) at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4031) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:128) at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:154) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:73) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:281) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:860) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2397) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:169) at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2193) at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2067) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:152) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4046) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:448) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:218) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:164) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86) at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4046) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:81) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onComplete(MonoPeekTerminal.java:299) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onComplete(MonoPeekTerminal.java:299) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:148) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:73) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:100) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:281) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:860) at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:249) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:100) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:118) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:295) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337) at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:118) at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2397) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:191) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:110) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:87) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCurrentContext.subscribe(MonoCurrentContext.java:36) at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:118) at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2397) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:191) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:169) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:110) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:87) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4046) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:448) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:218) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:164) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86) at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4046) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:173) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4046) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:81) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeekFuseable.java:940) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:84) at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2399) at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2193) at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2067) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4046) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:81) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:102) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:845) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:607) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:587) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:464) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeekFuseable.java:277) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:292) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:228) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:144) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:370) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:178) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:164) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86) at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157) at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:108) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:269) at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.signalCached(MonoCacheTime.java:328) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.onNext(MonoCacheTime.java:345) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:199) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:73) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOnCallable$CallableSubscribeOnSubscription.run(FluxSubscribeOnCallable.java:251) at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68) at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) "
}

this my controller code

```
@PostMapping("/users/addPhoto/{id}")
    public Mono<User> addPhoto(@RequestParam MultipartFile file,@PathVariable String id) throws IOException { 
        return userService.findById(id).flatMap(user->{
            try {
                user.setPhoto(new Binary(BsonBinarySubType.BINARY, file.getBytes()));
            return  userService.save(user);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return Mono.just(user);

            }
        });
        
    }
```

Comment: welcome to SO, please provide the piece of code that you are using and log errors.

Comment: Hey, as Felipe asked, would you be able to edit your post and provide the error you're getting, as well as some basic troubleshooting steps you've tried? Thanks!

Comment: i have just edited my post ,i added my security configuration class and also the customized web filter class .PS:the customized webfilter class raises  a "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter"

Comment: can you guys help me with this problem ??@Felipe @ Adam 'Crashdoom' Walker